# Why do some humanoid robots use a slanted yaw joint on the hip?

Tags: joint, humanoid

In this image, we see LHipYawPitch, as well as a dedicated LHipPitch. Why would they combine the yaw and pitch in the upper joint instead of making a dedicated yaw joint? I understand that this makes it more similar to a human hip, but is there any practical advantage?

[image]

Comment: why are you singling out the hip joint? ... several other joints in the picture appear to use the same design

Comment: @jsotola Which other joints combine yaw and pitch on the same axis? I'm not referring to two separate joints that intersect (such as ankle or shoulder), I'm referring to a single joint that rotates along a skewed axis.